# Which group isomorphism theorem is being used here?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism

I am reading a proof of the Jordan Holder theorem given [here](http://www.math.brown.edu/~abrmovic/MA/f1516/251/JordanHolder.pdf). (relevant part is given below)

When the author says that $K_i= K\cap G_i$ in the second paragraph, I do not understand the proof of how $K_i/K_{i+1}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_i/G_{i+1}.$
First I am not sure which isomorphism theorem is being used here. Furthermore, I am not sure how one can say the image is normal and the kernel is $K_{i+1}.$ Perhaps someone can offer an explanation.

[image: Relevant Part here]