# Show that the $A/B$ is a normal subgroup of $G/H.$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Goal:  To show that $A_{i}/A_{i+1}$ is a normal subgroup of $B_i/B_{i+1}.$

We are given that

1. $B_{i} \triangleright B_{i+1}.$
2. $B_{i} \triangleright  A_i.$
3. $A_i \triangleright A_{i+1}.$
4. $A_{i}\subset  B_{i}$
5. $A_i=B_1\cap K_1\cap B_i$, where $K_1$ is another normal subgroup of $G.$

where $G\triangleright H$ means that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G.$

I have taken the projection $\pi:B_i\to B_i/B_{i+1}.$ Then 
$$\ker(\pi_{|A_i}) = A_i\cap B_{i+1} = B_1\cap K_1\cap B_i \cap B_{i+1} = A_{i+1}.$$
So $$A_i/A_{i+1}\cong \text{image}(\pi_{|A_i})$$
since the $ \text{image}(\pi_{|A_i})$ is normal in $B_{i}/B_{i+1}$ we have that $A_i/A_{i+1}$ is a normal subgroup in $B_{i}/B_{i+1}.$ Is this correct reasoning?

This is related to the question I previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384584/which-group-isomorphism-theorem-is-being-used-here).

Comment: I think you mean "is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of", not "is a normal subgroup of".

Comment: I understand, but the notes that I am reading require it to be a normal subgroup.

Comment: @model_checker $A/B$ **is not** even a subset (let alone a subgroup) of $G/H$ unless $B=H$. So it doesn't make sense. It seems that you want to show that some **image** of $A/B$ is a normal subgroup of $G/H$?

Comment: @freakish that will help me follow the proof given in the link. Perhaps there is a mistake there?